# How to target specific header in WordPress h1, h2, h3 etc

Tags: html, css

I have a specific header `h1` I'd like to target but it's div class doesn't appear to work.

Html:

```
<h1>Design Consultancy</h1><div 
class="mb32"><p>Design 
Consultancy</p>
</div><a class="btn btn-lg btn- 
filled" 
href="https://adsler.co.uk">Design
</a><a class="btn btn-lg btn- 
white"href="http://4309.co.uk/
portraits/">Illustration</a>                                 
</div>
```

Tried css.

```
.mb32 {color:black !important;}
```

Nothing.

http://4309.co.uk

I'm trying to target the words `design Consultancy`

Comment: You know that `h1` doesn't have that class...right?

Comment: Hi Pauli. How are you? Yes, but how can target h1 please? Thanks.

Comment: Based on that class...you can't. A **proper** demo is required.

Comment: Find this rule `.image-bg h3, .image-bg h1 {color: #fff;}` and disable it.

Comment: Can I just unset it?

Comment: `image-bg h3, .image-bg h1 {color: unset;}`

Comment: That's up to you. That's the current controlling rule

Comment: Hey. That worked. @Paulie_D you're a genius. Thanks.

Comment: Post it and I'll mark correct

Comment: `.image-bg h3, .image-bg h1 {color: yellow;}` worked.